# RateLimitExceeded shortening URLs using Goog.gl, but usage far below limits?

Tags: rate-limiting, goo.gl

I'm piping a list of URLs through the Goo.gl link shortener, and have a business account with an API that's being read (when I omit it, I get an un-auth'd error, and I see requests logged in my account)

But my rate limit is not being respected?

After 300 requests (about one per second) I get:

```
{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"rateLimitExceeded", "message"=>"Rate Limit Exceeded"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Rate Limit Exceeded"}}
```

Until I stop for a few minutes. If I request again too soon (few minutes), I can get one link shortened, then go back to `rateLimitExceeded`.

If I wait an hour or so (not sure exactly) I can rescan another 300.

What's going on, why is my quota 1,000,000 / day, and 1,000 / second and I'm still getting limited?

Comment: Sounds like question for Google support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775593/google-url-shortener-403-rate-limit-exceeded

Comment: The per second rate limit is much lower than stated in your OP: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas#general_api

Comment: Different quota for the API i'm using, and it's configurable http://cl.ly/image/3o3M1U243H1y

Comment: I think you linked to the wrong screenshot.

Comment: Ahh, yup. Thanks @Sonny http://cl.ly/image/44053G212K2u

Comment: "If your application makes all API requests from a single IP address (i.e. on behalf of your users) you should consider using the userIP or quotaUser parameters with each request to get full QPS quota for each user."

Comment: Where did you find that? I googled, and only found it talking about the Analytics api. I'm using the goo.gl url shortener.

Comment: Based on the documentation that I linked to, it looks like the quotas are shared across all of the APIs.

Comment: *Between all the Analytics-related apis.

Comment: It's the best I've been able to find.