# android Urlshortener not working with signed apk

Tags: android, google-url-shortener

Trying to integrate goo.gl url shortner with the android app. 
The app works fine in debug mode .But it gives the error when tried in the released/signed apk.
Any help/pointer is appreciated.
Attaching the error snapshot in signed apk.[image]

Comment: Clearly appear in response that your daily quota is for expire for the day with that specific account. You must be using free quota . [See this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas) and Maybe [this So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775593/google-url-shortener-403-rate-limit-exceeded) help .

Comment: do you enable progaurd for release version?

Comment: yes i enable proguard..

Comment: @ADM the same app is working when run in debug mode i.e unsigned apk.